# jquery how to get the title attr?

Tags: jquery

i have a simple example:

```
<a id="my_videos" href="#" title="123"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
<a id="my_videos" href="#" title="223"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
<a id="my_videos" href="#" title="323"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>

$('#my_videos').live('click', function() {
    var ide = $('#my_videos').attr('title');
    alert (ide);
});
```

what happens is that every time i click on the link the same value pops up `123`

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/RDvUZ/3/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rename `id="my_videos"` to `class="my_videos"`. IDs should be unique. Then, use `this` inside the event listener, to refer to the just-clicked element.

```
<a class="my_videos" href="#" title="123"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
<a class="my_videos" href="#" title="223"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
<a class="my_videos" href="#" title="323"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>

$('.my_videos').live('click', function() {
    var ide = this.title;
    alert (ide);
});
```

For this case, Vanilla JavaScript is more clear. If you want to use jQuery to get the title, use:

```
var ide = $(this).attr('title');
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case is the use of multiple instances of the same ID.

ID by definition can only occur once on the entire page. No 2 elements may have the same ID.

That is why when jQuery searches for the element you clicked, it only finds the first element with that ID. You'll have to use a **class name** instead.

Also, you should use `$(this)` to refer to the element that triggered the event (the one you clicked) and not some random element that matches the selector.

```
$('.my_videos').live('click', function() { //Note the classname use and not id
    var ide = $(this).attr('title');
    alert(ide);
});
```

Or an even shorter version using JavaScript's native `this`:

```
$('.my_videos').live('click', function() {
    var ide = this.title;
    alert(ide);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have `this` instead of `#my_videos`:

```
$('#my_videos').live('click', function() {
    var ide = $(this).attr('title');
    alert (ide);
});
```